# Distance from a point on a circle to another when the angle between them is given

Tags: geometry

[image]

There are two points on a circle and the angle between them is known, as well as the radius of the circle. What I want to do is find the horizontal and vertical distance between these points. Is there any way to do that?(the distance given by the horizontal&vertical yellow lines)

Comment: use the law of sines  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Answer (score 1):

Using the law of sines you easily get
$$d= \sqrt 2 r \sqrt {1 - \cos x}$$

where d is the hypotenuse of your yellow triangle.

Answer (score 1):

If the radius of the circle is *r*, then using the law of cosines the length of the chord joining the two points is

$$
\begin{align*}
c &= \sqrt{r^2 + r^2 - 2r^2\cos{x}}
\\ &= r\sqrt{2(1 - \cos{x})}
\end{align*}
$$

However, to find the horizontal and vertical components of the distance you need to know the location of the points. This is because if you imagine the same angle in a different position on the circle (such as A and B below), the chord length is the same but the horizontal and vertical components are different. Here is a diagram made with Isosceles:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better to use $t$ or $\theta $ for the angle so as not to confuse with $x$ coordinate.

Top  Start Point

$$ (x,y)= (0,r) $$

End Point

$$ (x,y)= r [ \sin t, \cos t] $$

Horizontal and Vertical distances of your yellow lines ( please thicken them ), are $x$ and $y$ distance differences respectively.

Use the distance relation

$$ d^2 = 2 \, r^2 (1- \cos t), \quad d = r\sqrt{2  (1- \cos t) }. $$